# Extract class names from scss files to json file when building with webpack

Tags: css, json, webpack, sass, extract

I need to extract class names from scss files and emit to json file as array when webpack is building scss.

I can't find any webpack plugin to do that.

Example source file

```
.wp-block-media-text {
    &.is-xp-vertical {
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows: none;

        .wp-block-media-text__media {
            grid-column: 1;
            grid-row: 1;

            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .wp-block-media-text__media img {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
    }
}
```

For example output in json will be

```
{
    "extractedClassNames": [
        "wp-block-media-text",
        "is-xp-vertical",
        "wp-block-media-text__media"
     ]
}
```

Comment: its good that you show the result. it helps me for understanding if i could see also the source.

Comment: Sure I can share my webpack config too if you about that.

Answer (score 0):

with this regex ( https://regex101.com/r/caVgH9/1 )

`(\.[^ {]+)`

you could get class names as array

use all but not the first

Comment: Yes this regex is cool, but how I can do it with webpack and dynamically create json file?